# Change the default pip Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda

When I run `pip show pip` on Powershell, it returns me : `c:\users\thomas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`

and when I run `python -m pip show pip`, it returns me : `c:\python310\lib\site-packages`

I would like to know if there is a way to replace the default current pip to the one when I run `python -m pip show pip` without using aliases and virtual environement.

I tried to write a `pip.ini` file with :

```
[global]
target = c:\python310\lib\site-packages
```

but it hasn't change anything.

Comment: program `pip` is normal python script. You can open it in text editor and modify. On Linux it needs to change first line with `hashbang` (`#!`) - ie. `#!/usr/bin/python3` and it will run this script using `/usr/bin/python3`. But I don't know how it works on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` or `python` are executables on your computer and when you run the pip or the python command Windows uses environment variables to invoke software. You need to modify your environment variables (paths) to change the pip or the python version.

- `pip` (`pip show pip`): somewhere_on_your_computer\Python\Python310\Scripts
- `python` (`python -m pip show pip`):  somewhere_on_your_computer\Python\Python310

My setup (In the list the order is important):
[image]

[image]